# JavaScript - issue about figure out console.log return on longest subsequence algorithm

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this complex algorithm exercise. At this moment, I have some difficulty understanding it at all. So I decided to split the code into small parts. At this moment I want to understand only the `console.log`'s return. In the future, I will post other doubts.

Below, here is solution came from this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10WnvBk9sZc

```
longestSubseq("ABAZDC", "BACBAD") //ABAD
longestSubseq("AGGTAB", "GXTXAYB") //GTAB
longestSubseq("aaaa", "aa") //aa
longestSubseq("", "...") //""
longestSubseq("ABBA", "ABCABA")//ABBA

function longestSubseq(s1, s2, s1StartIdx = 0, s2StartIdx = 0) {
  const results = []  

  for(let s1Idx = s1StartIdx; s1Idx < s1.length; s1Idx++) {
    const s1Char = s1[s1Idx]
    const s2Idx = s2.indexOf(s1Char, s2StartIdx)    
    let result = []

    //Here is the highlight of my doubt
    console.log('s1Idx: ' + s1Idx)
    console.log('s2Idx: ' + s2Idx)
    console.log('s1Char: ' + s1Char)

    if(s2Idx !== -1) {
      result.push(s1Char, ...longestSubseq(s1,s2,s1Idx + 1, s2Idx + 1))
    }

    results.push(result)   
  }

  const longest = findLongest(results)
    return longest.join('')  
}


function findLongest(arr) {
  let longest = []

  for (let candidate of arr ) {
    if(candidate.length > longest.length) {
      longest = candidate
    }
  }

  return longest
}
```

Let do it based on this example:

```
 longestSubseq("ABAZDC", "BACBAD") //ABAD
```

In this code above, into of the `for` of `longestSubseq function`...

```
 console.log('s1Idx: ' + s1Idx)
 console.log('s2Idx: ' + s2Idx)
 console.log('s1Char: ' + s1Char)
```

It returns in the console:

```
s1Idx: 0
s2Idx: 1
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 1
s2Idx: 3
s1Char: B
s1Idx: 2
s2Idx: 4
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 2
s2Idx: 4
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 1
s2Idx: 0
s1Char: B
s1Idx: 2
s2Idx: 1
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 2
s2Idx: 1
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
```

I did understand the begin of the return involving these lines below, with the loop passing throught these letters: 'ABAZDC'

```
 s1Idx: 0
 s2Idx: 1
 s1Char: A
 s1Idx: 1
 s2Idx: 3
 s1Char: B
 s1Idx: 2
 s2Idx: 4
 s1Char: A
 s1Idx: 3
 s2Idx: -1
 s1Char: Z
 s1Idx: 4
 s2Idx: 5
 s1Char: D
 s1Idx: 5
 s2Idx: -1
 s1Char: C
 s1Idx: 5
 s2Idx: -1
```

I did NOT understand the loop continues, resulting these returns below printing the repeated letters 
C,Z,D,C,C,A,Z,C,C,Z,D,C,C,B,A,Z...

```
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 2
s2Idx: 4
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 1
s2Idx: 0
s1Char: B
s1Idx: 2
s2Idx: 1
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 2
s2Idx: 1
s1Char: A
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 3
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: Z
s1Idx: 4
s2Idx: 5
s1Char: D
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: -1
s1Char: C
s1Idx: 5
s2Idx: 2
s1Char: C
```

Answer (score 0):

How code execute you can check here step by step

[python-tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#code=function%20longestSubseq%28s1,%20s2,%20s1StartIdx%20%3D%200,%20s2StartIdx%20%3D%200%29%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20results%20%3D%20%5B%5D%20%20%0A%0A%20%20for%28let%20s1Idx%20%3D%20s1StartIdx%3B%20s1Idx%20%3C%20s1.length%3B%20s1Idx%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20s1Char%20%3D%20s1%5Bs1Idx%5D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20s2Idx%20%3D%20s2.indexOf%28s1Char,%20s2StartIdx%29%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%28s2Idx%20!%3D%3D%20-1%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20result.push%28s1Char,%20...longestSubseq%28s1,s2,s1Idx%20%2B%201,%20s2Idx%20%2B%201%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20results.push%28result%29%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20const%20longest%20%3D%20findLongest%28results%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20longest.join%28''%29%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afunction%20findLongest%28arr%29%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20longest%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0A%20%20for%20%28let%20candidate%20of%20arr%20%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28candidate.length%20%3E%20longest.length%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20longest%20%3D%20candidate%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20longest%0A%7D%0A%0AlongestSubseq%28%22ABAZDC%22,%20%22BACBAD%22%29%20//ABAD&cumulative=false&curInstr=12&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

First try to understand how [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) works

second [Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

so  `result.push(s1Char, ...longestSubseq(s1,s2,s1Idx + 1, s2Idx + 1))`

this function call recursively  `longestSubseq(s1,s2,s1Idx + 1, s2Idx + 1)`